# Git - File stuck in staging area

Tags: git

I was stuck trying to remove a certain file I accidentally added to the staging area.

I referenced multiple sites and other answers (attempts below) but still could not get it to work.

Here's what I did...

1. I wanted to commit the changes I did to the xml files in my project, but accidentally used `git add *xml` before I realised that would add all other xmls that were untracked to my staging area.
2. No problem I thought, and ran `git restore --staged *xml` according to the git prompt to `(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)`
3. While a bunch of xml under my build directory got removed, a particular XML in my `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory remained
4. Cue the failed attempts to remove that stubborn XML...

```
git restore --staged src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml
git reset
git reset HEAD~1
git rm --cached src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml
```

5. All the commands got executed successfully but that stubborn xml remains in my staging area...

```
$ git status
On branch feature/config-updates
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature/config-updates' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml
```

6. Eventually I did `git restore --staged .` and that miraculously worked.

**Any idea why the previous commands did not work?**

Comment: `git status` shows that a tracked file is marked for deletion, which means that `git rm --cached .../stubborn.xml` worked.

Comment: at some point, you ran `git reset HEAD~1`, which means the *active commit* got changed. Other commands (which use `HEAD` as a reference : `git status`, `git restore` ...) will therefore have a different behavior. Check your current commit, and check your `git reflog` to confirm the current commit is the one you expect.

Comment: @LeGEC you're right, the /src was a typo when I typed this question. I checked my command history and confirmed that I did type in the file correctly. I run a `git status` after every command but I see the xml file in the staging area every time (whether it was marked as deleted or not I can no longer confirm), that is till I did step 6...

Comment: ok, I deleted the noisy comment. Like I said : your `HEAD` commit changed. Can you check the status of the `stubborn.xml` file in both commits ? in particular : is it missing in one commit and present in the other one ?

Comment: @LeGEC doesn't look like it... I ran `git log --follow -p -- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml`, the last change was in April. File present in both commits...

Comment: in your sequence of actions, `git reset HEAD~1` made you "go back one commit". Have you done anything that brought you back to your initial commit ?

Comment: I did execute `git reset --hard` (I was ready to redo my changes after failing to remove that stubborn.xml) and then `git pull`, which would have brought me back to the remote HEAD

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long because I'm not sure how to write it any shorter.

(Also, I'm suspicious that you may be using Windows or macOS, on a case-insensitive file system, and might have committed files whose name differs only in case.  That's hard to diagnose without more information though.)

#### What you did

When you ran:

> ```
> git restore --staged src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml
> ```

Git read the `HEAD` version of `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml` from the `HEAD` commit, and copied that version of that file to Git's index / staging-area.  (Note that files in the staging area have these long names containing slashes in them: they're not folders-and-files, they're just files, with long names that have forward slashes.)

With the `--staged` option but no `--worktree` option, `git restore` writes *only* the index copy.  The existing working tree copy, present or absent, remains unchanged (remains present unchanged, or remains absent).

When you ran:

> ```
> git reset
> ```

Git read the `HEAD` version of *every* file from the `HEAD` commit, and copied those versions of those files into Git's index.  Since this is a `--mixed` reset, not a `--hard` reset, it stopped there, not touching your working tree.  It actually did one other thing first, but that one other thing was a no-op (didn't *accomplish* anything) so I didn't mention it until now.

When you ran:

> ```
> git reset HEAD~1
> ```

Git:

1. moved the *current branch name* `feature/config-updates` back one hop, to the first parent of the current commit; then
2. read every file from the *new* (stepped-back-one-hop) commit into Git's index.

Again, since this is a `--mixed` reset, Git did not touch any of the working tree files.

When you ran:

> ```
> git rm --cached src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml
> ```

Git removed, from its staging area, the file named `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml`.  Since that file was in the *current commit*, that file was now "staged for removal":

```
$ git status
...
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/stubborn.xml
```

We also see the effect of forcing the branch name back one hop:

```
On branch feature/config-updates
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature/config-updates' by 1 commit ...
```

Your last command:

> ```
> git restore --staged .
> ```

has the same effect as running `git reset` (with no arguments at all), provided you're in the top level of your working tree (which is likely).  This would re-load Git's index with the committed version of the file, from the current commit (which, again, is one step behind).

#### What you probably should do now

You probably want to run:

```
git reset origin/feature/config-updates
```

now, to fix things.  Note that this is a `--mixed` reset, so it does not touch your working tree.

#### What's going on

The way to understand this is to realize what Git's index / staging-area really is.  Except for ... well, a lot of things , it's actually very simple: Git has, at all times, not one, not two, but *three* "active" copies of every file.

Remember that a Git *commit* is a two-part entity.  It holds (a) a full snapshot of *every* file, in a special, read-only, Git-ified, frozen, compressed, and *de-duplicated* format.  Only Git can read these files, and literally nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite them.<sup>1</sup>  And, it holds (b) some metadata, or information about the commit.  But neither of these is any good for *using the files*.  In order to use the files, we need ordinary OS files, that any program can read *or write* (or both).

What this means is that we don't actually work with commits directly.  Instead, we tell Git to *check out* some commit.  To do that, Git reads the compressed, Git-ified files out of the commit–reads the frozen archive, in other words—and *expands* those files back out to ordinary everyday files.  It's these ordinary everyday files that we see and work on: Git stuffs those into our *working tree* or *work-tree*.

Almost all version control systems use this same scheme: there's some archived copies, saved forever (or a good long time at least), and then there's the usable working ones.  So the fact that there are *two* copies—one frozen, one useful—of each file is not surprising.  The surprise here is that there's a *third copy*.

Well, I say "copy", but: that third copy—the *index* copy—is in Git's frozen-and-de-duplicated *format*.  It's not quite frozen, in that you can remove-and-replace it, or remove it entirely, and you can add new files, that Git didn't know about before, too.  But it's in the de-duplicated format, and at least initially, *every file in the index came out of the commit* so *all of them are duplicates* so *all of them take no space*.

The index entries themselves, which carry the file's name and mode and a bunch of cache data so that Git can tell if you've changed the *working tree* copy, take some space.  This comes to very roughly 100 bytes per file (the amount depends in part on the length of the file's name, though the names are compressed via a fancy scheme that means that it's not always obvious how long the name is in the index: it's *not* the length of the file's name alone).  **This index, with its file entries plus some other stuff meant to make Git go faster and have fancy features, *is* the staging area.**  So this is where the third "copy" of each file is: in Git's index.

As you run `git add` or `git rm`, what you're doing is *updating the index entry*.  A `git add` of an existing file has Git:

- read the working tree copy and compress it;
- check to see if that's a duplicate of some existing file (in *any* commit): if so, use that one; if not, make the compressed copy ready to save; and in either case, we now have a hash ID for the file;
- *update* the index entry for the file with the new hash ID (and new cache data for speed later).

So `git add` of some existing file *replaces* the index copy with a new "copy", pre-de-duplicated as appropriate, ready to be committed.

Using `git add` on a file name that *isn't* in the index right now does the same steps, except that instead of replacing the existing copy, Git adds the new file name.  So again, the index now has the file ready to be committed.

Using `git rm` (`--cached` or not) on a file that's in the index has Git *remove* the "copy" of the file from the index.  With `--cached`, Git stops here; without `--cached` Git *also* removes the working tree copy.  In either case, the index now has the lack-of-file (the "deletion") ready to be committed.

**In all cases, the index has the next commit ready to go.**  We start out with the index matching the *current commit*.  It's ready to go into a new commit, though because this exactly matches the *current* commit, Git will object to the attempt to make a new commit ("nothing added to commit").  Then we use `git add` and/or `git rm`: this *updates the index*, and now it's ready to go into a new commit.  It's *always* ready to go!<sup>2</sup>

**So that's what this is: the index holds your *proposed next commit*.**  As such, we (and Git now) call it the *staging area*, since we're going to make a snapshot of the "stage" on which all the files (furniture?) are carefully arranged to make a pretty picture (a useful set of files).  The index doesn't hold *changes*.  It holds *files*, ready to go.

**We don't normally look at the whole index / staging-area** because in a big repository it shows way too much, and that's entirely unnecessary.<sup>3</sup>  We're not really interested in the fact that 99,997 files are unchanged!  We want to know about the three files out of the 100k files that *are* changed.  So `git status` works by:

1. *comparing* all the files in `HEAD` vs the index: whatever is the same, is boring, and we don't hear about it; whatever is *different* is `staged for commit` and we do.
2. *comparing* all the files in the index vs our working tree copies: whatever is the same, that's boring, and we hear nothing; whatever is *different* is `not staged for commit`.

As a special case, files in our working tree that aren't in the index at all are *untracked*.  We hear about those as a complaint: *hey, look at all these untracked files! wouldn't you like to add them? huh? huh? let's add 'em!*  If we find these complaints annoying, we can *list* these files in a `.gitignore` file, and that makes Git shut up about them.  It also makes en-masse "add all files" operations like `git add .` *not add them*.  But if those listed files are *already in Git's index*, their presence in `.gitignore` is irrelevant: they're *tracked* and Git now cares about them.

What all *this* means is this: **Understanding the index, or staging area, in Git is absolutely critical to using Git correctly.**  Any attempt to bypass the index ultimately leads to tears and lost files.  *Don't skimp on this!*  People like to use `git commit -a` to pretend that they don't need to understand the index.  It works for a while, and then it doesn't.  Don't do that.  Know what the index / staging area is.

You don't (yet, maybe never) need to know about the conflicted-merge "staging slots" stuff, but you do need to know that the index holds your *proposed next snapshot*.  Doing a `git checkout` fills in both Git's index *and* your working tree.  You work with files that *are not in Git*—are only in your working tree—and then you use `git add` and/or `git rm` to update the *proposed commit* in the index / staging-area.  And then, once the proposed commit is what you *want* to commit, you run `git commit`, and Git makes the new commit from whatever is in the index—regardless of whether it matches what's in your working tree!

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, your OS can overwrite or remove them, but doing so damages the repository badly.  Don't let cloud-synchronizing software on your OS at the repository either as that too can overwrite or remove them and thus damage your repository.  Overwriting these files damages them; because of their special, compressed, Git-ified, de-duplicated nature, treating them as ordinary OS files will ruin them.  (It's safe to *read* them, but the result is compressed nonsense, unless you know the internal Git formats.  There are two in use: one is actually pretty easy to read, and one is not.)

<sup>2</sup>There's an exception here that comes up during `git merge`, or other things that use Git's merge engine.  When a merge is *conflicted*, Git will store *more than one version* of some file into the index, in what Git calls extra "staging slots".  In this case, the index isn't ready to be committed: `git commit` will complain that you have unmerged entries, and will refuse to run.  The "resolve the merge" work you do consists of fixing up the index so that there's only *one* entry for each file, in "staging slot zero".  So the *expanded*, unmerged, index is uncommittable—but other than that, it's still "ready for commit", sort of: what you do during the resolving is to clear out the extras, and move something to slot zero, or maybe remove all the slots if the file should just be omitted.

<sup>3</sup>If you want to see what's in the index—it's a good exercise, at least in a small repository, where it won't list 100,000 entries—use `git ls-files --stage`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I'm going to do it justice and read it properly when I get some time to focus on this. I had much simpler assumptions about how git works and this answer makes me realise how little thought I gave to how Git works behind the scenes.